# Cannot instantiate the type WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, installation, webdriver

I have just started with Selenium and have already hit a problem.

Simple enough, but I'm totally missing it, just trying to create an instance of WebDriver but getting the error cannot instantiate...

[image]

I have all the jar files, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I guess you should specify browser you want to use, like `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: I shouldn't have to should I? But I'll give it a go

Comment: I don't ```WebDriver``` an abstract class? Have you tried creating an instance of a specific implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is giving error because WebDriver is a interface not a class. so create object of webdriver as below:-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In the above statement, WebDriver is an interface. An interface contains empty methods that have been defined but not implemented. These methods can be implemented by anyone as long as the method type and signatures are not violated. Therefore, an interface is also known as contract, because you can use an interface as you like but you cannot change the way it has been defined. And, since it has empty methods you won't actually need to instantiate it and so you cannot instantiate it.

FirefoxDriver is a class that has been written specifically for the Firefox browser. It has methods that are implemented and it can be instantiated. It can perform all functions (or methods) on the Firefox browser as defined in the interface WebDriver.

So in the above statement, we are actually telling FirefoxDriver class that "hey you can automate the various methods that you want on the Firefox browser but you need to stick to the contract defined in WebDriver". So we declare a reference variable of type WebDriver and then use it to instantiate FirefoxDriver, which means that the object (driver) is of type WebDriver but points to the memory allocation to all data and methods in FirefoxDriver (and, as mentioned above, the FirefoxDriver class already has the implemented version of methods in WebDriver). So all good :)

By using this technique, we have made it easy for the tester to use any browser of his or her liking. For example, to automate on IE driver, one will have to simply write a statement like

```
WebDriver driver = new IEDriver();
```